# Google Oauth consent screen only shows progress bar

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-api, scopes

My application is a simple application that backs up many stories, I try to use google OAuth to load the application folder in users' Google Drive, I log in successfully as a user and select my account But I do not see the consent screen or the Google access screen.
I only see the Progressbar and the blank page

[image: my client id]

[image: and consent screen]

[image: login screen]

[image: and consent screen]

can anyone help me please...

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: I am having the exact same issue, and I am using Google's sign in example